# Deploy a pre existing django git repo to heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, github

I have a DJango git repository.Me and some other developers are working on it and it has multiple branchs also. Now i want to deploy it to Heroku or want to use the heroku as a staging server means before pushing to git i want to push the code changes to heroku and if verified will push changes to git. For this i have created a heroku app using this git repo by running

```
heroku create
```

command for heruku. But the problem is when i make a commit it is directly committed to the git not to the heroku.

I have tried to delete the heroku app from the local git repo by running

```
 `heroku apps:destroy –a guarded-tundra-1589 --confirm`
```

but when i again tried to push the heroku master code is pushed to it. means it doesn't get deleted.

Tell me the right way to deploy the project which already has a git repo to heroku.

Answer (score 2):

There are standart Heroku commands to do this:

```
$ heroku auth:login
... output omitted ...
$ heroku create --stack cedar
... output omitted ...
$ git commit -a -m 'Mods to run on Heroku.'
$ git push heroku master
```

UPDATE:

Also if you are planning to use Heroku in future it could be useful frt you to check their official Documentation - [Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)

Comment: will i be able to use the heroku as a staging server after running these commands? or can you please tell me where the code will be committed when i will make a commit? on heroku or on my existing git repo?

Comment: @SajidAhmad git push heroku master - from this command we can see that push should be to Heroku app git.

Comment: okay, means when i will push the origin master it will be to origin and when i will push the heroku master it will be to heroku. Thnks. Lemme try this.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the update. DO i need to run the command `git add .` also before running the git commit command or it will add the files itself from git?'

Comment: I think you should add needed files by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete your repo, but this what worked for me when I got that error.

```
rm -rf .git
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```